# Android L2TP client and Windows RRAS 2012R2

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, rras, android, vpn-client

L2TP VPN server Windows RRAS 2012R2 confirmed working with a Windows Client and also an Ipad.  Confirmed locally remotely.

The Android client cannot connect.  The event logs on the Windows RRAS VPN server say that:

> The connection was prevented because of a policy configurd on your
>   RAS/VPN server. Specifically, the authentication method used by the
>   server to verify your username and password may not match the
>   authentication method configured in your connection profile.

How do I configure to allow Android L2TP VPN clients?  Any help would be appreciated. It doesn't appear to be straightforward to allow specific auth/ciphers on the Windows vpn server.

Comment: Why you erased your other question to create that one? you could edit the other (I would had erased my other comment to know it work on other platform)

Comment: @yagmoth555 Sorry I thought this was the appropriate action since the question changed